# Slow to install an enterprise IPA on a real device

Tags: ios

I'm creating enterprise signed builds of an iOS app for our test team. The app is 1.5 gigabytes. When I compile and run from Xcode it takes a couple of minutes to install. If I create an IPA and have them drag it into the device browser in Xcode, it can take an hour to install.

Has anyone who has seen this behavior found a way to speed the install? Jailbreaking is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I found someone offline who had a solution.

- Unzip the IPA. (In Finder you can rename it from .ipa to .zip then double-click on it).
- Open the resulting folder called "Payload".
- Drag the file in the folder into Xcode devices (or iTunes).

Copying is much, much faster than dragging the IPA.

Answer (score 0):

Installing through Xcode doesn't compress the app: it just downloads the binary to the device. An .ipa is a .zip file with a different extension—it's compressed, and 1.5 GB takes a while to decompress on an iOS device.

Comment: Amazing how long it takes compared to on a MacBook Pro!